# Seeing through your dollar

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

### Font Fest

Styles of writing
are not what this is about,
only one (and eleven...) is the key
keeping it single, no doubt.

Curvy and wavy,
I make things more,
onomatapeic,
I slide on the floor.

You're looking for one letter
or is it a number?
Get on with it -
Rise from your slumber!

**NEW Addition:**

'Font Fest' is not a string of letters,
...numbers - is more like it,
The missing one is the key,
So go and find it!

@shree.Pat18 got it bang on,
but clues he's still missing - no hate,
oh, and by the way,
eleven is now twenty-eight.

---

---

There are at least 9 clues hidden in the rhyme. 
Try and find them all!

**HINT:**

> We're looking for a letter of the alphabet.
> That letter completes the header ('Font Fest') of the poem which will answer some of the clues...

Answer (score 14):

Answer is

> S

Curvy and wavy,
I make things more

> 's' is a common suffix to make plurals.

onomatapeic,
I slide on the floor.

> That would a hissing snake.

Also,

> the dollar sign ($) looks almost identical to the letter S.

Related to the above,

> the single and double vertical lines are both acceptable variants of the dollar symbol

which ties back to only one (and eleven...) is the key

Comment: "Or is it a number" -> 5 is written almost the same as S

Comment: Yes... that is correct! However, you need to find all the clues. Try starting with how it 'completes' the header :-)

Comment: 'rise from your slumber' the S key is above the Z (zzzz  - sleep) key on QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: This may be unintentional, however, OP uses ellipsis in his riddle. *3 dots* in morse code is the letter S.

Comment: 'seeing through your dollar' refers to the vertical bar / I / eye / seeing combined with the letter S to make a dollar symbol $. Though thinking about it now shouldn't it be 'NOT seeing through your dollar', i.e. remove the I from a dollar to get the letter?

Comment: @LiamH no comment :-] :-]

Comment: "I make things more" plurals...

Comment: "Or is it a number?", maybe this helps: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet

Answer (score 6):

My try (partial. I'm working on the rest of the clues):

> The letter A.

Seeing through your dollar

> The 1$ bill has the "funny" pyramid that looks like an A.

Styles of writing
are not what this is about,

> The riddle can be about writing, but this is not the case, see rest of my guesses

only one (and eleven...) is the key

> A as in Ace can be 1 or 11 on Black Jack

keeping it single, no doubt.

> When playing Black Jack and you get 2 aces, you should split them.

Curvy and wavy,
I make things more,
onomatapeic,

> A when pronounced a s "Eeeeyyy" can be an onomatopoeic

I slide on the floor.

> guessing it's the Ace floor detergent
>  [image]

You're looking for one letter

> Yes. A is a letter

or is it a number?

> A represents 10 in base 16

Get on with it -
Rise from your slumber!

> Rise and became an Ace, maybe?

Comment: On "only one (and eleven...) is the key", 3 ones(1 or I) can build letter "A".

Comment: nice thinking :-) however not the answer intended. Spot on with it being a letter of the alphabet... However, the answer fits all clues better...

Comment: Note that ACE is a chain of hardware stores, so they have tons of products.  It's not like they are _known_ for the floor cleaner.

Comment: @JPhi1618. Aha...but they have it. :). I was shooting in the dark there. Anyway, the op confirmed that my answer is not the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is

> I

Seeing through your dollar

> The all-seeing "eye" (sounds like 'I')

Styles of writing
are not what this is about,

> Italics

only one (and eleven...) is the key

> 'I' is 1 in Roman numerals. (not sure about eleven, maybe 'II')

keeping it single, no doubt.

> 'I' is the first person singular subject pronoun.

Curvy and wavy,

> a curvy I is like an 'S'

I make things more,

> Add 's' for pluralisation

onomatapeic,
I slide on the floor.

> Snakes look like the letter 'S'

You're looking for one letter

> I

or is it a number?

> I is the Roman numeral for 1.

Get on with it -

> "Aye-aye"

Rise from your slumber!

> Could be referring to action on the part of "I".

There are at least 9 clues hidden in the rhyme. Try and find them all!

> 'I' is the ninth letter of the alphabet